# условия в mysql-запросе с динамическими данными

Tags: mysql, sql

Надо составить запрос: выбрать записи, до истечения срока которых осталось N дней.

Изначально `ticket.duedate` равен NULL, т.е. дата получается из IF'ов, без `WHERE` я получаю все записи(в них уже срок истечения), но мне нужны только те, дата истечения которых (dd) скоро наступит

```
SELECT 
  IF(ticket.duedate IS NULL,
    IF(sla.id IS NULL, 
      NULL, 
      DATE_ADD(ticket.created, INTERVAL sla.grace_period HOUR))
  ,ticket.duedate) as dd 
FROM ost3_ticket ticket
    LEFT JOIN ost3_sla sla ON (ticket.sla_id = sla.id AND sla.isactive = 1) 
WHERE dd > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

в ответ получаю `Unknown column 'dd' in 'where clause'` , как определить это поле что бы с ним можно было работать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы получаете ошибку `Unknown column 'dd' in 'where clause'`, потому что sql в `where` не знает, что такое dd.

Порядок выполнения sql-запроса другой - `from`, `where`, `group by`, `having`, `select`, `order`. Дойдя до `where`, он еще не видит столбец dd, который будет позже образован в `select`.

Таким образом, вам нужно явно пояснить, что такое dd в `where`:

```
SELECT 
  IF(ticket.duedate IS NULL,
    IF(sla.id IS NULL, 
      NULL, 
      DATE_ADD(ticket.created, INTERVAL sla.grace_period HOUR))
  ,ticket.duedate) as dd 
FROM ost3_ticket ticket
    LEFT JOIN ost3_sla sla ON (ticket.sla_id = sla.id AND sla.isactive = 1) 
WHERE IF(ticket.duedate IS NULL,
    IF(sla.id IS NULL, NULL, DATE_ADD(ticket.created, INTERVAL sla.grace_period HOUR)),ticket.duedate) > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Либо (в mysql вроде можно использовать этот трюк) так:

```
SELECT 
  IF(ticket.duedate IS NULL,
    IF(sla.id IS NULL, 
      NULL, 
      DATE_ADD(ticket.created, INTERVAL sla.grace_period HOUR))
  ,ticket.duedate) as dd 
FROM ost3_ticket ticket
    LEFT JOIN ost3_sla sla ON (ticket.sla_id = sla.id AND sla.isactive = 1) 
HAVING dd > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

---

*P.S. не совсем понятна схема БД, поэтому ответ написан лишь как избежать ошибки в выполнении запроса. Правильность выполнения скрипта вам стоит посмотреть самому.*